# Can you give the Greek Word ekklēsia a masculine ending?

Tags: greek, word-study, grammar

I know that the Greek word translated as church (in the Bible) is a feminine noun.
But, is it possible to give ecclesia a masculine ending - making it a masculine noun? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it would be better addressed at our sister site, [Latin Language](https://latin.stackexchange.com/) who have been accepting NT Greek language questions since 2018.

Comment: _Adjectives, participles and pronouns, by contrast, must be able to decline in all genders to agree with the gender of the noun (or antecedent) they modify._ Also from p.[60](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=erTxCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) as below. But nouns, themselves, are fixed in gender.

Answer (score 1):

As Strauss wrote, “Nouns in Greek do not change their gender.”<sup>1</sup> The Greek noun ἐκκλησία has a feminine grammatical gender which never changes.

```
Footnotes
```

<sup><sup>1</sup> p. [60](https://books.google.com/books?id=erTxCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT60&#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>

---

**References**

Strauss, Mark L. [*The Biblical Greek Companion for Bible Software Users.*](https://books.google.com/books?id=erTxCgAAQBAJ) Grand Rapids: Zondervan, 2016.

Comment: thank you. appreciate it.